# Lucene Index MAXFieldLength

Tags: lucene

I'm new to Lucene and I'm using Lucene with Java. I'm reading the lucene in action book which covers 2.4 version. In the same the max field length will be set to unlimited in the index writer constructor  argument. Now refer ed to the javadocs and I inferred that the if we want to set the field length then we have use the LimitTokeneAnalyser. I ran a sample program, in that I instantiated a standard analyser and checked with the gerMaxFieldLength method which returned 255. So is it only possible to index 255 filed using standard analyser and the unlimited field length  option has been deprecated or not. Can we achieve this any way. Does the maxField length denotes that the  number of characters in the field of that document is 255?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength is present in Lucene up through v3.0.2 at least. As of v3.0.2, the default for MaxFieldLength is 10,000.

Answer (score 1):

In the `LimitTokenCountAnalyzer` constructor you could easily set this '`maxTokenCount`', and here is the API:

> [https://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/LimitTokenCountAnalyzer.html#LimitTokenCountAnalyzer(org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer](https://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/LimitTokenCountAnalyzer.html#LimitTokenCountAnalyzer%28org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer),
>   int)